# Search Bar смещается вниз после нажатия на него (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

Есть такой код, который создает `Search Bar`. После того, как производится нажатие на этот самый `Search Bar`, то происходит его смещение вниз вместе с кнопкой "Отменить". Прилагаю скриншоты и код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@IBAction func showSearchBar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
   self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([], animated: true)

   self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

   self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self 
   self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self 
   self.searchController.delegate = self

   self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
   self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
   self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
   self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Искать продукты"

   self.searchController.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
   self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal

   self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
   self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

}

Как избавиться от этого смещения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пихать searchBar в titleView не очень хорошая идея. Можно конечно, запихать его вместо leftBarButtonItem и задать ему фрейм, тогда будет нормально работать.
Но, все же, я бы рекомендовал делать так как советуют Apple, вставить searchController в navigationItem, а именно заменить вот эту строчку

```
navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

на эту

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

да, и `self` тут не нужен